# How to create a scoreboard on a Rock Paper Scissors Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to make a rock, paper, scissors game as a beginner into JavaScript.

**My Game Plan is:**

After the user has clicked an option (rock, paper, scissors) it will show them their score and computer score. It will show the result. Once their score has reached a certain amount, they are able to type their name in and it will log it somewhere.

Can someone please tell me on how to do this, I am a beginner and it would be nice if someone can show me how to do this. Please view it a;l on the JS Fiddle webpage. I am incorporating HTML and CSS.

I am doing it on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y3qu7pzz/

Thanks

```js
enter code here: This is the JS
function playgame (x){

var options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

var playerChoice = x

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)

var computerChoice = options[randomNumber]

function determineWinner(){
 //
 if (playerChoice == computerChoice) {
   //
   $("#results").html("You selected " + playerChoice + " and the computer selected " + computerChoice + ". Game tied.<br />")
  } 
  //
  else if (playerChoice == "rock" && computerChoice == "paper" || playerChoice == "scissors" && computerChoice == "rock" || playerChoice == "paper" && computerChoice == "scissors") {
   //
   $("#results").html("You selected " + playerChoice + " and the computer selected " + computerChoice + ". You lost. <br />")   
  } 
  //
  else if (playerChoice == "rock" && computerChoice == "scissors" || playerChoice == "scissors" && computerChoice == "paper" || playerChoice == "paper" && computerChoice == "rock") {
   //
    $("#results").html("You selected " + playerChoice + " and the computer selected " + computerChoice + ". You won. <br />") 
 } 
  //
  else {
   //
   alert("Please enter rock, paper or scissors")
  }
}
//
determineWinner()

} 

$(".start").click(function (){
var choice = $(this).attr("id")
playgame(choice)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is functioning. You said you want to store the score somewhere. The first part would be to include a score and increment as appropriate. 
You could store a global var with the number of times the computer won and the number of times the player won

```
var computerWins = 0;
var playerWins = 0;
var draws = 0;
```

In `determineWinner()`

```
//computer wins conditional
computerWins++;
...
//player wins conditional
playerWins++;
//..etc
```

finally calc the score for percentage of wins:

```
var percentageWins = (playerWins / (computerWins + playerWins + draws)) * 100;
```

Display to the user etc.

You may wish to store the score in `localstorage` so if the user leaves the page and comes back it will still be persistent. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

You want to set/get the wins/draws vars from `localstorage`.
Alternatively you could post the data to some endpoint and retrieve it but that would require an additional server.

Comment: What does ... mean. I try to put this into my JS but it isn't working. Also how wold I display this to the user? Alert? I tried different things, but it isn't working. 

https://jsfiddle.net/y3qu7pzz/8/

That is my code, please help me.